# Resend user activation mail

Tags: users, activation, email-verification

We've set up a small Wordpress environment and added about 150 users by importing an excel document through the User Meta plugin. The Wordpress environment is build for a wedding and lets users fill in their address (complete profile) after an email with username, password and e-mail confirmation link. Because the people who are getting married do have all email addresses of their guests but don't have all the actual home addresses.

Most of the users (± 100) read the email and confirmed their email and completed their profile. But there are still 50 users who are pending, they did receive the first email with username and password but did not activate/complete their profile. Does anyone know how to resend this activation mail to the pending users?

Comment: There is a plugin called `Unconfirmed`, Try using it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/unconfirmed/

Comment: Thanx, already tried that one. It does not seem to work, when going the settings page of this plugin it says:

Unconfirmed
Search:
No unactivated members were found.

Comment: You may find the activation status of an account in usermeta table, bsaed on the status you can send the email again.

Comment: We found this to be the best solution so far. Found this plugin on github: Resend Welcome Email. https://github.com/atwellpub/resend-welcome-email

Comment: trac ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31127